# How can I decompile Perl 6?

Tags: raku

We're supposed to be able to do this somehow. I think I've seen it somewhere, but I can't find what I think I remember. Mostly I want to see how the compiler interprets code.

Along with decompiling, is there a way to watch what it's doing as it compiles? I think seeing what's it's trying to do and where might be easier than trying to understand some of its error messages. And, decompiling a program can undo all the shorthand and cleverness to elucidate what's actually happening.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure why you would want to do it. Also, the compilation result is backend dependent, and you did not specify a backend. Anyway, with the `--target=` parameter, you can get intermediate results. The most useful are:

```
$ perl6 --target=parse -e 'say "foo"'
- statementlist: say "foo"
  - statement: 1 matches
    - EXPR: say "foo"
      - args:  "foo"
        - arglist: "foo"
          - EXPR: "foo"
            - value: "foo"
              - quote: "foo"
                - nibble: foo
      - longname: say
        - name: say
          - identifier: say
          - morename:  isa NQPArray
        - colonpair:  isa NQPArray
```

`--target=parse` shows the immediate result of the parse.

```
$ perl6 --target=ast -e 'say "foo"'
- QAST::CompUnit  :W<?> :UNIT<?>
  [pre_deserialize]
    - QAST::Stmt 
      - QAST::Stmt 
        - QAST::Op(loadbytecode)
          - QAST::VM 
            [jvm]
              - QAST::SVal(ModuleLoader.class) 
            [moar]
              - QAST::SVal(ModuleLoader.moarvm) 
        - QAST::Op(callmethod load_module) 
*snip*
```

`--target=ast` shows the Abstract Syntax Trees.

```
$ perl6 --target=mast -e 'say "foo"'
MAST::Frame name<<unit-outer>>, cuuid<2>
  Local types: 0<obj>, 1<obj>, 2<obj>, 3<obj>, 
  Outer: <none>
  Instructions:
  [0] MAST::Op getcode
    MAST::Local index<3>
    MAST::Frame name<<unit>>, cuuid<1>
  [1] MAST::Op capturelex
    MAST::Local index<3>
  [2] MAST::Op getcode
    MAST::Local index<1>
    MAST::Frame name<<unit>>, cuuid<1>
  [3] MAST::Op takeclosure
*snip*
```

And `--target=mast` shows the actual byte code that is being generated, in this case for the MoarVM backend.

Comment: Does `--target=ast` show the state before or after simplification / static optimization? And is there a more readable form of the post-optimization state? I understood the question as asking if there is something like Perl 5's [`B::Deparse`](https://metacpan.org/pod/B::Deparse), which serializes the optimized "byte code" back to Perl code, allowing you to see how the compiler "understood" what you wrote, and if e.g. two syntaxes are considered identical by the compiler. (And I too would love to see something like that in Perl 6).

Comment: For example, it would make it easy to check how precedence is resolved in golfed expressions without whitespace; and whether or not `if $a == 1|2 { ... }` is compiled into `if $a == 1 || $a == 2 { ... }`; etc.

Comment: @smls, `--target=ast` shows before static optimizer. Use `--target=optimize` to see the after. You can also use `RAKUDO_OPTIMIZER_DEBUG=1` env var that'll print a bunch of info on what optimizer is doing as well as before, after, and all the steps in-between